# List Document Files in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to know about basic questions .

1) I need to download some data from my app ..where should i store it in (document directory or in some other path).

2) if i store in the document directory in ..delete my app ..then would not the my all downloaded data be deleted.

3) my downloaded data can be of increasing space size means in GBs, so where should i store it.

**below code gives me list data of the document directory**

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"path %@",documentsDirectory);
 filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
NSLog(@"af%@",filePathsArray);
```

4) if i need to list data of the some specific folder say `"/users"` then what should be changes in the code.

Comment: @H2CO3 ya man I am aware of the code ..i just need to know where should i store the data in `NSCachesDirectory` or `NSDocumentDirectory` ..to keep it remain in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Apple prefers that downloaded data be stored in the app's `Caches` directory since the data can be replaced if it is deleted.

2) Yes, if a user deletes an app, all data stored in the app's sandbox will be deleted. What would you expect to happen?

3) Use `NSCachesDirectory`.

4) `/Users` is not a valid path in an app's sandbox. You may see such a path when running in the simulator but not on a real device.

Apple's docs talks all about the iOS file system and the structure of the app's sandbox. You really should start by reading those docs.

BTW - every one of these answers can be found with a few minutes using Google or searching this site. That is why you are getting all of the down votes. Please put some effort into finding your own answers before posting questions. Please read the (whole) FAQ.

Comment: ok thanks man...like need to keep safe the data into my memory ...so i will be using`NSCachesDirectory`instead of `NSDocumentDirectory`  but later how can i access the data through code...bcz address would be change `..Applications/2492C5CE-CD36-4270-8BB8-25710C24BF9E/Library/Caches` for the same app ..ryt

Comment: Files in the Caches directory can be deleted by the OS. You will need to download them again in the unlikely event that this happens. The code you posted (plus changing `NSDocumentDirectory` to `NSCachesDirectory`) is basically how you access the data.